# Google DRIVE API V3 - Get a root folder ID with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-drive-shared-drive

I need to get root folder id and filter folders which have root folder as their parent folder. Using Nodejs and google drive API v3 .
This is my code and how I change this code to get root folderId?

```js
const service = google.drive('v3');
   service.files.list({
   auth: client2,
   fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, webContentLink, webViewLink, mimeType, parents)'
     }, (err, res) => {
   if (err) {
     console.error('The API returned an error.');
     throw err;
   }
   const files = res.data.files;
   if (files.length === 0) {
     console.log('No files found.');
   } else {
    
     console.log('Files Found!');
     for (const file of files) {
       console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);

     }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The folder id of the root folder is "root".  The file.list method has an option parameter called [q](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters) which is used for searching.

```
 service.files.list({auth: auth,
    resource: { parents: [ folderId ] },
    q: "'root' in parents",
    fields: '*',
    spaces: 'drive',
    pageToken: pageToken,
  }
```

This code is kind of a guess as i dont have the power to test node on this machine.

Comment: Thank you that really helped me out.